# How to specify an error should be ignore in a HTML file in vscode?

Tags: html, flask, visual-studio-code, jinja2

I used a Jinja2 statement in a HTML file:

```
<div class="row" id="msg-bar" style="display: {{ 'none' if request.method=='GET' else 'block' }}">
        <div class="alert {{ 'alert-primary' if status=='Success' else 'alert-danger'}} " role="alert">
            {{ status }}
        </div>
</div>
```

But the vscode always pops up a note which said it has some errors in  `style="display: {{ 'none' if request.method=='GET' else 'block' }}`

How can I specify an error should be ignore in a HTML file in vscode?

Comment: jave you tried adding `"html.validate.styles": false` to your `.vscode/settings.json`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install "Better Jinja" extension and select language mode "Jinja HTML"
[image]